# Sprite isn't showing up in unity 2D

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, sprite, tic-tac-toe

I'm starting to program at the moment but have already encountered my first problems.

I Try to program a tic tac toe game with unity using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6rrTYR221w&t=635s. Unfortunately, when I press a field, I don't see the sprite, but the field takes a value so you can win or lose, but don't see where X or O are. The code changes from : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz2YI.jpg to https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLwMN.jpg or https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdRbe.jpg but nothing happens except when I change it myself.

I tried several things but I have not come any further, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the alpha value on the images is set to 0.
Open the color picker and set value A to 255